# Application insight

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have created a powerBI dashboard for my application insight but it's only showing last 7 days data. 
I am able see 30 days when I check in overview of appinsight but it's only showing last 7 days when I do browser search from overview view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are exporting you Application Insights telemetry to PowerBI, but you can export the data using [Application Insights Analytics queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-power-bi#export-analytics-queries). This way, you have full control on the timestamp range in the Analytics query.

For example, for finding the average request duration in the last 30 days in a daily bin, you can use the following query:

```
request
| where timestamp >= ago(30d)
| summarize avg(duration) by bin(timestamp, 1d)
```

Asaf